# react-hook-form radio with custom style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a form (react-hook-form) for update data with two options radio.
In this form I can read datas and display it.
But when I want to change the value, my interface doesn't update the display.
Where am I wrong?

Here is my code snippet :

```
<Controller
       name={`evaluations.${index}.check`}
       control={control}
       render={({ field }) => {
           return (
              <>
                <div className={'radioCheck'}>
                <input
                   {...field}
                   style={{ display: "none" }}
                   type='radio'
                   name={auditEval.checkpoint?.id.toString()}
                   id={`ok${auditEval.checkpoint?.id}`}
                   value={'true'}
                   defaultChecked={auditEval.check == true}
                />
                <label htmlFor={`ok${auditEval.checkpoint?.id}`}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                </label>
             </div>
             <div className={'radioCross'}>
             <input
               {...field}
               style={{ display: "none" }}
               type='radio'
               name={auditEval.checkpoint?.id.toString()}
               id={`nok${auditEval.checkpoint?.id}`}
               value={'false'}
               defaultChecked={auditEval.check == false}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`nok${auditEval.checkpoint?.id}`}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faX} />
            </label>
          </div>
       </>
     )
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

To solve it, I had to use the "watch" function in react-hook-form

Answer (score 0):

you can try using state and write inside style setting:

```
const [ bord, setBord ] = useState('solid blue 2px');
```

and in error msg:

```
style={{border:`${bord}`}}
```